# Trying to get Facebook Cookie from codebehind, but is getting (OAuthException)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK on my site, and is trying to access the cookie made by Facebook when the user has chosen to use Facebook as login, but I am getting the following error:

> (OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 var client = new FacebookClient([App ID], [App Secret]);
 dynamic me = client.Get("me"); 
 string firstName = me.first_name;

 Response.Write(firstName);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to authorize first before trying to access the user. This does the necessary redirects and plumbing to have Facebook set the cookie.

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new string[] {"user_about_me"} };
if (auth.Authorize()) {
    var client = new FacebookClient([App ID], [App Secret]);
    dynamic me = client.Get("me"); 
    string firstName = me.first_name;
    Response.Write(firstName);
}
```